# Delete blank lines within range

Tags: range, global-command

Suppose I have the file:

```
begin
asdf

asdf
end

begin

asdf
end

begin
asdfasdf

end
```

How can I use something like the global command to delete every empty line in between 'begin' and 'end'?

`:/begin/,/end/ g/^$/d` only deletes the space in the first begin/end block.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the very general case, the `:g` command cannot be called recursively. There is one exception:
Since Vim patch [8.0.0630](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.0.0630), one can call a recursive `:g` command, if it operates only within a single line. So you can do something like (quoting the [help](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#E147)):

> When the command is used recursively, it only works on one line. 
>   Giving a range is then not allowed. This is useful to find all lines
>   that match a pattern and do not match another pattern:
>
> ```
>     :g/found/v/notfound/{cmd}
> ```
>
> This first finds all lines containing "found", but only executes {cmd} 
>   when there is no match for "notfound".

However that means, this does not apply to your use case here. You would need to call `:g` to mark all `begin/end` regions, and then call another `:g` command to find empty lines (to be deleted).

However, in your case, you can use the `:s` command like this:

```
g/begin/,/end/s/^\n//
```

Note: We are searching for line start (`^`), followed by a line break (`\n`), because we want to remove this line break, effectively deleting the empty line. For that reason using the pattern `^$` to the `:s` command would not work, as it would leave the empty line intact (keep the line break).

Answer (score 1):

You could instead try this: `:g/begin/,/end/ s/^$//`. I don't think `g` works recursively, so using `s` instead seems to do the job.